# open card on click to display more details

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am trying to display more detail with the openDetail function for one card at a time. How would I get that detail to just show up in the window once the card is clicked? right now I get an error that function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick. but it is passing the correct id to the on click.I copied my problem below.

```js
const formatAuthors = (authors) => {
  return authors.map(author => author.person).join(', ') || 'Anonymous';
};

$(() => {
  const url = "https://data.azgs.arizona.edu/api/v1/metadata";

  $('.destinations-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let searchstring = $('input[type="text"]').val();
    let requestUrl = url + `?text=${searchstring}&title=${searchstring}`;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: requestUrl,
      success: function(res) {
        //Create a button to see more info, or add an click event handler for the whole .res-entry div
        //Change item.metadata.id for whatever property contains the ID
        let repo = res.data.map(item =>
          `<div class="res-entry" href="#" onclick="openDetails(${item.collection_id},event)">
     <div class="res-entry-title">${item.metadata.title}</div>
     <div class="res-entry-author">${formatAuthors(item.metadata.authors)}</div>         
     <div class="res-entry-series">${item.metadata.series}</div>
     <div class="res-entry-download">
       <a href="${item.links[0].href}">Download</a>
     </div>
      </div>`);

        $("#results").empty().append(repo); // Empty previous...
      }
    });
  });

  function openDetails(id, ev) {
    //This is for crossbrowser compatibility
    (ev || event).preventDefault();
    //Fetch the item's details (replace detailsRequestUrl for whatever URL can return the contents)
    $.get({
      url: "https://data.azgs.arizona.edu/api/v1/metadata?collection_id=",
      data: {
        id: id
      },
      success: function(res) {
        var details = $("#details");
        //Build the HTML
        details.html(res.data.map(item =>
          `....`));
        //And open the popup
        details.show().fadeTo(200, 1);
      }
    });
  }

})
```

```css
#results {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.res-entry {
  border: thin solid grey;
  margin: 0.667em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-title {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-author {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-author:before {
  content: 'By: ';
}

.res-entry .res-entry-series {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-download {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-download a {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  /* If you want it on the right */
}

.res-entry .res-entry-download a button {
  border: thin solid grey;
  background: #FFF;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-download a button:hover {
  border: thin solid grey;
  background: #EE7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#details {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="destinations-form" role="search">
  <div class="input-line">
    <input id="searchForm" type="text" class="form-input check-value" placeholder="Search Documents" />
    <button type="submit" class="form-submit btn btn-special">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
        <div class="boat-box">
          <div id="results"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="col-md-18 col-md-30 center">
        <div id="details"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding `onclick` dynamically which will not work. You need to add an `.on` listener to the `document` for your `.res-entry` class:

```
$(document).on("click", ".res-entry", e => {    
    openDetails($(e.target).data("id"), e)
})
```

Check the code below:

```js
const formatAuthors = (authors) => {
  return authors.map(author => author.person).join(', ') || 'Anonymous';
};

$(() => {
  const url = "https://data.azgs.arizona.edu/api/v1/metadata";

  $('.destinations-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let searchstring = $('input[type="text"]').val();
    let requestUrl = url + `?text=${searchstring}&title=${searchstring}`;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: requestUrl,
      success: function(res) {
        //Create a button to see more info, or add an click event handler for the whole .res-entry div
        //Change item.metadata.id for whatever property contains the ID
        let repo = res.data.map(item =>
          `<div class="res-entry" href="#" data-id="${item.collection_id}">
     <div class="res-entry-title">${item.metadata.title}</div>
     <div class="res-entry-author">${formatAuthors(item.metadata.authors)}</div>         
     <div class="res-entry-series">${item.metadata.series}</div>
     <div class="res-entry-download">
       <a href="${item.links[0].href}">Download</a>
     </div>
      </div>`);

        $("#results").empty().append(repo); // Empty previous...
      }
    });
  });


  $(document).on("click", ".res-entry", e => {    
    openDetails($(e.target).data("id"), e)
  })

  function openDetails(id, ev) {
    //This is for crossbrowser compatibility
    (ev || event).preventDefault();
    //Fetch the item's details (replace detailsRequestUrl for whatever URL can return the contents)
    $.get({
      url: "https://data.azgs.arizona.edu/api/v1/metadata",
      data: {
        collection_id: id
      },
      success: function(res) {
        console.log(res)
        /*var details = $("#details");
        //Build the HTML
        details.html(res.data.map(item =>
          `....`));
        //And open the popup
        details.show().fadeTo(200, 1);*/
      }
    });
  }

})
```

```css
#results {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.res-entry {
  border: thin solid grey;
  margin: 0.667em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-title {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-author {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-author:before {
  content: 'By: ';
}

.res-entry .res-entry-series {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-download {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-download a {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  /* If you want it on the right */
}

.res-entry .res-entry-download a button {
  border: thin solid grey;
  background: #FFF;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-download a button:hover {
  border: thin solid grey;
  background: #EE7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#details {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="destinations-form" role="search">
  <div class="input-line">
    <input id="searchForm" type="text" class="form-input check-value" placeholder="Search Documents" />
    <button type="submit" class="form-submit btn btn-special">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
        <div class="boat-box">
          <div id="results"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="col-md-18 col-md-30 center">
        <div id="details"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I see it showing up in the console log but not in the HTML itself. Is that because I didn't hide the other cards?

Comment: @Lbook I only wrote the code till the point you can get the correct response, after that you need to map it correctly to html the way you need it to. Your original code for creating the html from response is there in the comments, you should modify that. Do accept if the answer helped you

Comment: It still doesn't give you the correct response. it adds =id in front of it

Comment: I am still having trouble with just passing one id on click. It works sometimes and others it brings in the whole 10.

Comment: @Lbook Yes so that is not an issue on our end. Its the wrong result from the API. You can always select the first one from that right?

Comment: yeah! it will always be the first one.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible happened because the insert openDetails after the DOM load, I'm not sure about this.
Therefore you can use ".on" instead on every element called `.res-entry`

```js
const formatAuthors = (authors) => {
  return authors.map(author => author.person).join(', ') || 'Anonymous';
};

$(() => {
  const url = "https://data.azgs.arizona.edu/api/v1/metadata";

  $('.destinations-form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let searchstring = $('input[type="text"]').val();
    let requestUrl = url + `?text=${searchstring}&title=${searchstring}`;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: requestUrl,
      success: function(res) {
        //Create a button to see more info, or add an click event handler for the whole .res-entry div
        //Change item.metadata.id for whatever property contains the ID
        let repo = res.data.map(item =>
          `<div class="res-entry" href="#" data-id="${item.collection_id}">
     <div class="res-entry-title">${item.metadata.title}</div>
     <div class="res-entry-author">${formatAuthors(item.metadata.authors)}</div>         
     <div class="res-entry-series">${item.metadata.series}</div>
     <div class="res-entry-download">
       <a href="${item.links[0].href}">Download</a>
     </div>
      </div>`);

        $("#results").empty().append(repo); // Empty previous...
        
        $(document).on("click", "div.res-entry" , function(ev) {
            const id = this.getAttribute('data-id');
            // Then do your request
            openDetails(ev, id);
        });
      }
    });
  });
  
  

  function openDetails(ev, id) {
    //This is for crossbrowser compatibility
    (ev || event).preventDefault();
    
    console.log(id);
    //Fetch the item's details (replace detailsRequestUrl for whatever URL can return the contents)
    $.get({
      url: "https://data.azgs.arizona.edu/api/v1/metadata?collection_id=",
      data: {
        id: id
      },
      success: function(res) {
        var details = $("#details");
        //Build the HTML
        details.html(res.data.map(item =>
          `....`));
        //And open the popup
        details.show().fadeTo(200, 1);
      }
    });
  }

})
```

```css
#results {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.res-entry {
  border: thin solid grey;
  margin: 0.667em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-title {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-author {
  font-size: 0.8em;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-author:before {
  content: 'By: ';
}

.res-entry .res-entry-series {
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-download {
  margin-top: 0.5em;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-download a {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  /* If you want it on the right */
}

.res-entry .res-entry-download a button {
  border: thin solid grey;
  background: #FFF;
}

.res-entry .res-entry-download a button:hover {
  border: thin solid grey;
  background: #EE7;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#details {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background: #fff;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="destinations-form" role="search">
  <div class="input-line">
    <input id="searchForm" type="text" class="form-input check-value" placeholder="Search Documents" />
    <button type="submit" class="form-submit btn btn-special">Search</button>
  </div>
</form>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-24">
        <div class="boat-box">
          <div id="results"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="col-md-18 col-md-30 center">
        <div id="details"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```